# Java regex to find a sequence of characters in a string

Tags: java, regex

I would like to find out if my string has = & & sequence in it. If yes then I would like to encode second &. How using java regex can I find it?

My string is something like this:

> a=cat&b=dog&cat&c=monkey

Thanks
Chaitanya

Comment: Are you looking for exactly `=&&` in the string, or can there be other characters between the `=`, `&`, and the second `&`?

Comment: a=cat&b=dog&cat&c=monkey

not exactly =&& but with some characters in between = and & and & as in above string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mosty and Ted suggested, perhaps the best way to go at this is by detecting and escaping the '&'.

However, if you want a single regex to do the work for you, here it is:

```
String s = "a=cat&b=dog&cat&c=monkey";

s = s.replaceAll("&(?=[^=]*&)", "&amp;");

System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

The regex has basically two parts:
`&`
`(?=[^=]*&)`

The first section detects an '&', which is the character you want to replace.

The second part is trickier. You need to make sure that after the '&' that you have just detected, the next sequence of characters contains another '&' and no '=' until that next '&'.

Comment: You do this by using a zero-width positive lookahead.This special construct let's you test a given condition for the characters that are 'ahead' of your match.  
The syntax for this is:  
  
`(?=X)` 
  
Where X is the condition that you want to test. In this case, X is:   
  
`[^=]*&`  
  
Or in other words: " any character that is no '=', zero or more times, followed by an '&' ".  
  
So in the end you get `&(?=[^=]*&)`, which means: " an '&' for which the following sequence of characters has no '=' up until the next '&' ".

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it?

First split it by "&", then take the second element

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format:

```
if (string.contains("=&&"))
{
 // do something
}
else
{
 // do something else
}
```

I don't know what you mean by "encode the &" though. Could you clarify?

Comment: Forget about encoding. Apologies.

I want to know that a=cat&b=dog&cat&c=monkey has = and some chars & and some chars & pattern in it..

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to escape the `&` in the values before forming the concatenated name-value pair string. But given an already-encoded string, I think a variant of Mosty's suggestion might work best:

```
String escapeAmpersands(String nvp) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] pairs = nvp.split("&");
    if (pairs[0].indexOf('=') < 0) {
        // Maybe do something smarter with "a&b=cat&c=dog"?
        throw new Exception("Can't handle names with '&'");
    }
    sb.append(pairs[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
        String pair = pairs[i];
        sb.append(pair.indexOf('=') < 0 ? "&amp;" : "&");
        sb.append(pair);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is likely to be faster than regular trying to do this with regular expressions.